# in Jenkins is there a way to minimize the jobs listing in the board?

Tags: jenkins

**Situation:**

Sometimes to simplify a task, we split it in tree parts to simplify the code.

**Problem:**

Now the quantity of jobs in the board is starting to be excessive since some jobs are splitted in 5 parts.
Like this, but only the build flow should be in the DashBoard :
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Splitting+a+big+job+into+smaller+jobs

**Solution:**

I know we can create a folder for each job, but we would have something else in mind. Would it be possible to have a build flow with 5 parts (subjobs), and that only the build flow (masterjobs) is in the dashboard, and the 5 subjobs are only existing within the build flow? So I can add infinity number of subjobs I want within the flow and I can only access them through there?

For example, the only way to find subjob 1 to 5 would be to be in the flow (masterjob), where you manage them?

I'm not sure if it's clear, if it's not I'll edit it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [View Job Filter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) plugin which in its simplest form allows for jobs to be filtered by a regular expression.

From the link:

> Regular Expression Job Filter
>
> With a large organization and hundreds
>   of jobs, it will become very annoying and time-consuming to try to
>   keep your views organized.  The regular expression job filter can
>   help, and there are multiple options to choose from to make it easier.
>
> Include/Exclude options - ability to either add jobs or filter out
>   jobs based on the expression, or the negation of the expression
>
> Job name - allows you to filter out jobs when you have naming conventions.
>   Also allows you to "narrow down" other filters, or to match the
>   negation of an expression
>
> Job description - if you use descriptions, this may help you get what you want

there are more in the wiki page